# How 'fair' is a Standard C++ atomic_flag in waking up threads from a wait() on a notify_one() call

Tags: c++, multithreading, concurrency, atomic, lock-free

Is there any information about fairness in relation to the sequence in which threads that called wait() on an atomic_flag are woken up when notify_one() is called. Are they woken-up in the exact order that they entered the wait(), FIFO so to say ?

Atomic flag variables seem to return 'always lock free'. I knew they were guaranteed to be lock free in any implementation but i am not sure about whether they still are if the wait() is used, and hence some mechanism must decide on waiters wake-up. Some other synchronization means guarantee fairness but it comes at a cost of memory allocation behind the scene.

Is there anyone that knows how this works with atomic_flags. I changed all my synchro's to use atomic flag and they work super fast. However I overlooked the fairness aspect.

Thank you.

Comment: AFAIK there's no fairness guarantee. Any arbitrary thread could wake up. Also remember that spurious wakeups can happen.

Comment: @Jesper, that would mean it would depend on the pre-emptive thread scheduler of the OS or so? First thread that gets a tick can check the flag. Still, someone must have implemented something to select that arbitrary thread, furthermore they work great on multi-core so i figure there must be something more doing the synchronization. About spurious wake-ups, that is something that I catch in my code, if any occur. Thx.

Comment: Yes it depends on the OS thread scheduler logic.

Comment: Btw; *Why* does it matter what idle/waiting thread wakes up? All the waiting threads are idle and (ignoring details like caches being warm/cold) it shouldn't matter which one wakes up to do the work..

Comment: @JesperJuhl It might not always be about picking up work, but continuing with other work. So in theory starvation could be a thing. But then again the OS thread scheduler should try to be "fair" and I would not know of anything a developer could/should do to create a better solution (at least the last thing developers should do is to start tinkering with thread priorities, that is a sure way to shoot yourself in the foot)

Comment: @Pepijn, I agree. The thread waiting the longest may see its output processed by other threads and cannot produce if it would be systematically overlooked in a wake-up strategy. And then there is the problem of multi-core. One would like its work as nicely as possible spread of the cores, hence over the threads on those cores. Thx.

Comment: If you have what @PepijnKramer says, and independent bits of work which you'd like to actually schedule, then it feels weird that you'd use a atomic at all. Just let the threads run and let the OS scheduler run. OS Scheduler have built in fancy mechanisms to boost priority of things which haven't run for a while, and also let lower pri threads get minimal but some time. All of which you seem to want. Using an atomic to notify doesn't seem (that) useful in this scenario. Atomics are usually used in pool scenarios where a bunch of (identical?) consumer threads can pick work up and run with it.

Comment: That said you may have a valid scenario between these two. You probably want to show that here and see if we can come up with a valid different solution. Unless you are simply asking about it for educations sake.

Comment: @Morph "One would like its work as nicely as possible spread of the cores, hence over the threads on those cores" - Threads are not (usually) locked to individual cores. Any thread can be woken up on any core (unless OS specific measures have been taken to pin threads to specific cores).

Answer (score 4):

There are no guarantees from the standard, it will depend on the implementation of the standard library.

It isn't even guaranteed that *only* one thread is unblocked. Any number of eligible threads, but at least one if at least one is eligible, may be unblocked. An implementation that simply forwards `notify_one` to `notify_all` would be conforming.

Answer (score 1):

In summary from the several answers the answer would be:

- the Standard C++ specs do not have any guidelines related to fairness of atomic_flags, and probably by extension to all other atomic types.
- each implementation may wake-up waiting threads as they see fit.
- using notify_all() instead of notify_one() would give all threads an almost equal chance to compete for the atomic_flag and leave it further to the scheduler.
- the preemptive thread scheduler leads the orchestra on what thread gets the first chance. I conclude from that, that with notify_all() starvation of a thread might become impossible, or less problematic at least, because each thread would be given chances by the scheduler.
- multi-core doesn't guarantee that a same thread always and completely executes on a same core anyways, so fairness would not bring anything to the table in attempting to better spreading load over the several cores.

Thank you all. Feel good now because that fairness is a lesser problem than i initially thought/feared.

Answer (score 0):

The C++ standard makes no requirements here - each implementation is free to wake the thread it finds most appropriate.

This is something you might want to compare across the compilers that exist for your platforms, if it matters to you.

Comment: Thx, its GNU for Linux and VS for Windows but I start to think that indeed fairness is less important if, as Jesper commented in OP, threads are executed over multiple cores anyways. Thx.